# SQL: combinig 2 rows into 1 row based on the first field in row

Tags: mysql, rows

I am not good in sql. I looked arround at stackoverflow but nothing seems to work for me. So, i am asking for help.  Is it possible to get 2 rows into 1 row based on first field in the row.

Im doing this in mysql. I will show the example.

This is my query.

```
SELECT `ps_product_attribute_combination`.`id_product_attribute`,`ps_attribute`.`id_attribute_group`,`ps_attribute_group_lang`.`name`,`ps_product_attribute_combination`.`id_attribute`,`ps_attribute_lang`.`name` 

FROM `ps_product_attribute_combination` 

LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute` 
ON `ps_product_attribute_combination`.`id_attribute`=`ps_attribute`.`id_attribute` 

LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_lang` 
ON `ps_attribute`.`id_attribute`=`ps_attribute_lang`.`id_attribute` 

LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_group_lang` 
ON `ps_attribute`.`id_attribute_group`=`ps_attribute_group_lang`.`id_attribute_group` 

WHERE `ps_attribute_lang`.`id_lang`='2' AND `ps_attribute_group_lang`.`id_lang`='2' 

ORDER BY `ps_product_attribute_combination`.`id_product_attribute` ASC, `ps_attribute`.`id_attribute_group` ASC
```

the output of this query is.

[image]

what i need is, based on the first field id_product_attribute = 0, to put all other information from second row to the end of first row (without the first field from second row)

the desired end result should be

[image]

How can i achive this? I want to learn. So any idea is appreciated. 
Thanks to all in forward.

Comment: could you create an sqlfiddle with some test data?

Comment: i can see a quick solution where you can use GROUP_CONCAT and handle the list returned in code.

Comment: example of GROUP_CONCAT here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3ca88/1

Comment: i appreciated your answer but those data like you created in sqlfiddle should not be mixed. i need to push to new columns the data from second row and the critera to do this, is the first field in first row. i could try to add the same fields to the end, and then to make group

Comment: maybe this one? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3ee3b/1

Comment: please make an answer so i can vote it. thanks, that´s what i need. and now comes the part to integrate the solution into my sql query

Comment: there i just copied and pasted in the answer

Comment: integrating should be straight forward, since you have you have your select as the inner T of my query..just add the group_concat calls and a group by.. then put the order by on the outer most query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3ee3b/1)

```
SELECT id_product_attribute,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_attribute_group,',',1) as id_attribute_group,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,',',1) as name,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_attribute,',',1) as id_attribute,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(name2,',',1) as name2,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_attribute_group,',',-1) as id_attribute_group2,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,',',-1) as name3,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_attribute,',',-1) as id_attribute2,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(name2,',',-1) as name4
FROM
(SELECT id_product_attribute, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(id_attribute_group) as id_attribute_group,
       GROUP_CONCAT(name) as name,GROUP_CONCAT(id_attribute) as id_attribute,
       GROUP_CONCAT(name2) as name2
FROM T
GROUP BY id_product_attribute)T2
```

Comment: and now the problem is with,commas. i have attribute sizes ex. 11,5 and then it shows just 5

Comment: try this using SEPARATOR pipe (|) that isn't a comma then parse using pipe (|) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/906aa6/2